# ProFTP uploads failure on replace

Tags: proftpd

Does someone know if it is possible to have proftpd to behave like this:

If a file is replaced but upload failed, then keep the  successfull old file.

To keep file integrity. It's because i'm using it with an app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, I would recommend using the following in your `proftpd.conf`:

```
HiddenStores on
```

The [HiddenStores](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_xfer.html#HiddenStores) behavior sounds like what you want: the file being uploaded by the client is stored by `proftpd` in a temporary "hidden" file.  When the upload completes successfully, that temporary file is atomically renamed into place.  If the upload fails, then the temporary file is deleted.

Hope this helps!